# Qt5: How to properly set a ProgressBar using State

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a small example of a `ProgressBar` that when it finishes to execute the loop should notify the user that the calculation finished.
To be specific, after the `ProgressBar` finishes, a `Text` should turn from `Connecting...` to `Connected`.

**The problem** is that as soon as the `ProgressBar` arrives at the end of the calculation the text does not change. I think that the problem might be on how I set the `finished` function of the `ProgressBar`. I have been trying to solve this problem for the last hours but there is some error I can't catch.

Below the most important part of the code:

**progressbardialog.h**

```
class ProgressBar : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(float progress READ progress NOTIFY progressChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(bool running READ running NOTIFY runningChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(bool finished READ finished NOTIFY finishedChanged)
public:
    ProgressBar();
    float progress();
    bool running();
    bool finished();

public Q_SLOTS:
    void startComputation();
    void cancelComputation();
    void finishComputation();
private Q_SLOTS:
    void updateProgress(int value);
signals:
    void progressChanged();
    void runningChanged();
    void finishedChanged();
private:
    bool m_running = false;
    int m_progressValue = 0;
    int m_finished = true;
    QVector<int> vector;
    QObject m_Model;
    QFutureWatcher<void> m_futureWatcher;
};
```

**progressbardialog.cpp**

```
ProgressBar::ProgressBar()
{}

void spinEC(int &iteration)
{
    Q_UNUSED(iteration)
    const int work = 1000 * 1000 * 400;
    volatile int v = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < work; ++j)
        ++v;
}

float ProgressBar::progress()
{
    return m_progressValue;
}

bool ProgressBar::running()
{
    return m_running;
}

bool ProgressBar::finished()
{
    return m_finished;
}

void ProgressBar::startComputation()
{
    m_running = true;
    emit runningChanged();
    // Prepare the vector
    vector.clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < 40; ++i)
        vector.append(i);
    const QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::map(vector, spinEC);
    m_futureWatcher.setFuture(future);
    connect(&m_futureWatcher, &QFutureWatcher<void>::progressValueChanged,
            this, &ProgressBar::updateProgress);
}

void ProgressBar::cancelComputation()
{
    m_running = false;
    emit runningChanged();
}

void ProgressBar::finishComputation()
{
    m_progressValue = false;
    emit progressChanged();
}

void ProgressBar::updateProgress(int value)
{
    m_progressValue = value;
    emit progressChanged();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
Text {
    id: connected
    text: qsTr("Not-Connected")
    color: "red"
    font.pointSize: 15
    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
    Layout.fillWidth: true

    states: [
        State {
            name: "connecting"
            when: pBar.running
            PropertyChanges {
                target: connected
                text: qsTr("Connecting...")
                color: "blue"
                font.bold: true
            }
        },
        State {
            name: "connected"
            when: pBar.finished
            PropertyChanges {
                target: connected
                text: qsTr("Yes! Connected...")
                color: "green"
                font.bold: true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**EDITS**:

On the **progressbar.cpp** I also tried the following in the function `void ProgressBar::finishComputation()` but also it didn't work:

```
void ProgressBar::finishComputation()
{
    m_progressValue = false;
    emit finishedChanged();
}
```

**What I have done so far** is debugging the code as much as possible and after debugging line per line (I could not find out and decided to go line by line) I figured out that the problem is on the `Q_PROPERTY` related to the `finished` function I wrote. 
All the other functions such as `running` and `progress` are working perfectly and applied the same exact philosophy to the `finished` function to notify the end of the calculation and, therefore, change the `State` from A to B of the `Text`.

What am I missing out in the `Progressbar` that is keeping me from finishing the exercise?
Thanks for shedding light on this matter.

Comment: Where do you change `m_finished = true;` and `emit finishedChanged();`?

Comment: @Amfasis, thank you very much for taking the time to read my question. Inside the function `void ProgressBar::finishComputation()` on the **progressbardialog.cpp** is what I was thinking,, but no matter what I tried it was never working

Comment: I edited the question in the part **EDITS** adding an additional think I tried but that didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be that m_finished is initialized with true in your header:

```
int m_finished = true;
```

So when the signal is emitted after the computation is done, QML doesn't detect any changes because the variable is still true!

Try changing it to false before starting the computation. Also don't forget to emit the changed signal each time running or finished change value:

```
void ProgressBar::startComputation()
{
    m_running = true;
    emit runningChanged();

    m_finished = false;
    emit finishedChanged();

    ...
}

void ProgressBar::finishComputation()
{
    m_finished = true;
    emit finishedChanged();

    m_running = false;
    emit runningChanged();
}
```

**EDIT:**

The Problem is that finishComputation is never called! A possible solution would be to add a check in your updateProgress function:

```
void ProgressBar::updateProgress(int value)
{
    m_progressValue = value;
    emit progressChanged();

    if (m_progressValue == 40)
        finishComputation();
}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your comments. Unfortunately it still doesn't work. If that could be helpfull [here](https://bitbucket.org/ERaggi/textchange/src/master/) is the minimal verifiable example of the `ProgressBar`

Comment: I see what I was missing! I was never calling it! Right! Thank you very much for your time it works great now! :)